# How do you call C functions from MacRuby?

Tags: macruby

I'd like to try to use MacRuby with CoreAudio on OS X, but most of these APIs are C functions. Do I have to use Ruby DL, or does MacRuby offer another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Macruby site, you should be able to call C functions directly

> **Accessing Static APIs**
>
> Many Mac OS X framework APIs are not introspectable because they are static, but thanks to the BridgeSupport project, static APIs can be called from MacRuby.
>
> The following API types are available:
>
> - List item
> - CoreFoundation types (CFType)
> - C structures
> - C opaque types
> - C enumerations
> - C and Objective-C constants (including preprocessor-defined constants)
> - C functions (including inline functions)
> - Objective-C informal protocols

http://www.macruby.org/documentation/tutorial.html